# node-ntwitter and twitter API Limites

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, twitter

Question related to the API limits, It might be something I'm just missing, not sure though:

If I do this:

```
 twit.showUser(ids, function(error, response) {
   console.log(response)
 }
```

Where {ids} is an Array, with length < 100, all is well.

When I do the same and IDs is > 100, it fails.

This is based on:
https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/users/lookup

And specifically:

> for up to 100 users per request

Is this somehow managed in ntwitter module or do I need to manage this outside? if so, any recommendation on how to manage that?

Or, outside of the node-ntwitter module, how would you recommend solving this in a clean way if I want to send back a composite json of all *responses* from showUser() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> for up to 100 users per request

means you can only request 100 ids at a time. You can run a for-loop with an increase of 100:

```
for(var i = 0; i < ids.length; i + 100) {
  requestIds = ids.slice(i, i+99)
  twit.showUser(requestIds, function(error, response) {
   console.log(response)
 }
}
```

*(untested)*

As it's node.js, you might want to have it asynchronous. Check out [forEachLimit](https://github.com/caolan/async#foreachlimitarr-limit-iterator-callback) and [forEachSeries](https://github.com/caolan/async#foreachseriesarr-iterator-callback).

Comment: showUser() is asynch, which means that the loop will be complete long before responses are return from the twitter api call.

Comment: Depends what you want to do inside the callback, but that's why I added the links for forEachLimit and forEachSeries ...

Comment: Thanks. What I want is basically to aggregate the response objects and send them back to the client.

Comment: That's definitely something for the async library.